# How to get value out of page.on function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Inside the page.on method I am parsing the 'content-disposition' header and retrieving the downloaded file name.

Can anyone tell me how I make the **filename** available outside of the **page.on** method??

```
page.on('response', response => {
   let url = response.request().url();
   let contentType = response.headers()['content-type'];
   if (contentType == 'audio/mpeg') {
      let contentDisposition = response.headers()['content-disposition'];
      let filename = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/)[1];
   }
});
```

Comment: Do you need just one response event and one file or do you need to catch many?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty I'm downloading a list of mp3 files, clicking on each separately so downloads only contain 1 file but there could be multiple happening.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty I can see the filename when I do a console.log(filename) but I can't figure out how to get it out of there so I can use it further down the script.

Answer (score 2):

After some more reading I think I was approaching it the wrong way by trying to use **page.on**, when I should have been using **page.waitForResponse**.

**page.waitForResponse** enables me to get each **filename** response immediately after each individual download **.click()** and use it in the trailing code.

**THE ONLY PROBLEM IS** this method does not seem to be as reliable as **page.on** and sometimes it misses a download happening then times out. I need to figure out a solution for why that happens.

```
const response = await page.waitForResponse(
    response => response.headers()['content-type'] == 'audio/mpeg'
);

let filename = response._headers['content-disposition'].match(/filename="(.+)"/)[1];

console.log(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `filename` outside the lambda and assign value within

```
let filename = undefined;
page.on('response', response => {
   let url = response.request().url();
   let contentType = response.headers()['content-type'];
   if (contentType == 'audio/mpeg') {
      let contentDisposition = response.headers()['content-disposition'];
      filename = contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/)[1];
   }
});
// later
if (filename) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the let filename doesn't get reassigned with the new value, it just stays undefined (or whatever I set it too).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
const [filename] = await Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    function handler(response) {
      let url = response.request().url();
      let contentType = response.headers()['content-type'];
      if (contentType == 'audio/mpeg') {
        page.off('response', handler);
        let contentDisposition = response.headers()['content-disposition'];
        resolve(contentDisposition.match(/filename="(.+)"/)[1]);
      }
    }

    page.on('response', handler);
  }),

  page.click(selector),
]);
```